# Add syntax highlighting support for Dockerfiles

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Highlight.js supports syntax highlighting Dockerfiles, but support is not present on Stack Exchange’s version of highlight.js. Please consider adding support for this.
Example question on Stack Overflow demonstrating missing feature:

[Pip upgrade cannot install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274325/pip-upgrade-cannot-install-packages)

Comment: FYI: Grammar for Dockerfile is 763 bytes before compression.

Comment: If anyone is using Chrome and interested in beta testing/contributing I wrote a Chrome extension that adds support (when hinted) for all the languages Highlight.js includes in the core library (as well as bundling a much more recent version of the library). https://github.com/joshgoebel/se_highlightjs